# Improving the readability, extensability, and optimization of a custom ETL Pipeline library (Pypeline.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, etl

I'm looking to improve the logic used in this ETL pipeline manager. The concept creates a structure:
`Pipeline(Pipe(Task, [Task, ...]), [Pipe(...), ...])`
...where a Pipeline contains one or more Pipes and a Pipe contains one or more Tasks.

Another important concept is the Operators, namely the `Handle`, `Wrangler`, and `Loader`.
These objects are callable arguments passed in during a Pipe's construction.

The `Handle` is the API client. It must accept the methods `self.initialize(credentials)` and `self.get_data(request)`.
The `Wrangler` is the part where data transformations are performed. It must accept the method `self.wrangle(Task)`.
The `Loader` is the part that handles loading the data into storage, or you could use it to do anything with the finished data really... It must accept the method `self.load(Task)`.

All operators, Tasks and Pipes maintain a property showing their status. They also maintain methods and attributes for a bunch of stuff like dynamically reading JSON files to swap out `in-string {{variables}}` with user provided kwargs.

Some of my planned next steps are to clean up some functionality for an object called MultiRequestTask, and introduce multithreading within the Pipeline object. I would also like to get feedback on it so far though.

Here's the code:

```
from enum import Enum
import traceback
from functools import wraps
from types import MappingProxyType
from typing import Mapping
from pandas import json_normalize
import textwrap
import json
import re


"""
Title: Pypeline
Current Version: 0.0.04
Created By: Chad Wood
Last Modified On: 20230208
Last Modification: Added logic to MultiRequestTask for performing sequenced requests. Options for improving the implementation should be explored, as it isn't exactly elegant at the moment. Review TaskOpsUtils._run_opperation() comments for more details.
"""

class StatusError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

class OpStatus(Enum):
    UNINITIALIZED = 'uninitialized'
    INITIALIZED = 'initialized'
    FAIL = 'fail' 
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
    
class TaskStatus(Enum):
    PENDING = 'pending'
    INCOMPLETE = 'incomplete'
    COMPLETE = 'complete'
    FAIL = 'fail'
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
    
class PipeStatus(Enum):
    IDLE = 'idle'
    READY = 'ready'
    INCOMPLETE = 'incomplete'
    COMPLETE = 'complete'
    FAIL = 'fail'
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value
    

class OperatorUtils:
    """
    Class containing utility functions for pipeline Operators.
    :param catch_runtime_errors:
    A flag indicating whether to catch and handle runtime errors.
    Default is True.
    :attribute:
    - catch_runtime_errors: A flag indicating whether to catch and handle runtime errors.
    :method:
    - _catch_runtime_errors(func):
    A staticmethod that acts as a decorator to catch and handle runtime errors
    in pipeline Operators. The decorated function will return a tuple of (response, error),
    where response is the function's output and error is None if no error occurs,
    otherwise it is a dictionary containing the error information.
    """
    def __init__(self, catch_runtime_errors=True):
        self.catch_runtime_errors = catch_runtime_errors
    
    @staticmethod
    def _catch_runtime_errors(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.catch_runtime_errors:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs), None
            else:
                try:
                    response = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                    return (response, None)
                except Exception as e:
                    error = dict(
                        type=e.__class__.__name__,
                        message=str(e),
                        trace=traceback.format_exc()
                    )
                return (None, error)     
        return wrapper

class Handle(OperatorUtils):
    """
    Class to handle the processing of data in the pipeline.
    :param api_client: A callable for handling data.
    :param args: Other positional arguments.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    :attribute:
    - initialize_error: None if no error occurred during initialization, otherwise contains the error information.
    - _status: The status of the Handle. Default is `OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED`.
    - api_client: The callable for handling data.
    :method:
    - initialize(credentials): Initializes the user supplied api_client.
    - status: A property that returns the current status of the Handle.
    - run(request, handle_operations={}): Handles the data using the provided `api_client` callable, with the provided `handle_operations`.
    """

    def __init__(self, api_client, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the Handle class.
        :param api_client: A callable for requesting data.
        :param kwargs: Flags passed to OperatorUtils
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._status = OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED
        self.api_client = api_client
        self.initialize_error = None
    
    def initialize(self, credentials):
        """
        Initialize the api_client object.
        
        :return: OpStatus (INITIALIZED or FAIL)
        :raises: Exception if error occurs during initialization
        """
        try:
            self.api_client = self.api_client(credentials)
            self._status = OpStatus.INITIALIZED
        except Exception as e:
            self._status = OpStatus.FAIL
            self.initialize_error = dict(
                type=e.__class__.__name__,
                message=str(e),
                trace=traceback.format_exc()
            )
            raise e from None
            
        return self._status
    
    @property
    def status(self) -> OpStatus:
        return self._status
    
    @OperatorUtils._catch_runtime_errors
    def run(self, request, handle_operations={}):
        if self._status == OpStatus.INITIALIZED:
            response = self.api_client.get_data(request, **handle_operations)
        else:
            raise StatusError(
                f'Can not run while Handle is {self._status}')
            
        return response
    
    
class Wrangler(OperatorUtils):
    """
    Class to handle wrangling of data in the pipeline.
    :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling data.
    :param args: Other positional arguments.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    :attribute:
    - initialize_error: None if no error occurred during initialization, otherwise contains the error information.
    - _status: The status of the Wrangler. Default is `OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED`.
    - wrangler: The callable for wrangling data.
    :method:
    - initialize(): Initializes the user supplied wrangler.
    - status: A property that returns the current status of the Wrangler.
    - run(data, wrangle_operations={}): Wrangles the data using the provided `wrangler` callable, with the provided `wrangle_operations`.
    """
    def __init__(self, wrangler, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the Wrangler class.
        :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling data.
        :param kwargs: Flags passed to OperatorUtils
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._status = OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED
        self.wrangler = wrangler
        self.initialize_error = None
    
    def initialize(self):
        """
        Initialize the wrangler object.
        
        :return: OpStatus (INITIALIZED or FAIL)
        :raises: Exception if error occurs during initialization
        """
        try:
            self.wrangler = self.wrangler()
            self._status = OpStatus.INITIALIZED
        except Exception as e:
            self._status = OpStatus.FAIL
            self.initialize_error = dict(
                type=e.__class__.__name__,
                message=str(e),
                trace=traceback.format_exc()
            )
            raise e from None
            
        return self._status
    
    @property
    def status(self) -> OpStatus:
        return self._status
    
    @OperatorUtils._catch_runtime_errors
    def run(self, data, wrangle_operations={}):
        if self._status == OpStatus.INITIALIZED:
            response = self.wrangler.wrangle(data, **wrangle_operations)
        else:
            raise StatusError(
                f'Can not run while Wrangler is {self._status}')
            
        return response
    
    
class Loader(OperatorUtils):
    """
    Class to handle loading of data in the pipeline.
    :param loader: A callable for loading data.
    :param args: Other positional arguments.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    
    :attribute:
    - initialize_error: None if no error occurred during initialization, otherwise contains the error information.
    - _status: The status of the Loader. Default is `OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED`.
    - loader: The callable for loading data.
    :method:
    - initialize(): Initializes the user supplied loader.
    - status: A property that returns the current status of the Loader.
    - run(data, load_operations={}): Loads the data using the provided `loader` callable, with the provided `load_operations`.
    """
    def __init__(self, loader, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the Loader class.
        :param loader: A callable for loading data.
        :param kwargs: Flags passed to OperatorUtils
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._status = OpStatus.UNINITIALIZED
        self.loader = loader
        self.initialize_error = None
    
    def initialize(self):
        """
        Initialize the loader object.
        
        :return: OpStatus (INITIALIZED or FAIL)
        :raises: Exception if error occurs during initialization
        """
        
        try:
            self.loader = self.loader()
            self._status = OpStatus.INITIALIZED
        except Exception as e:
            self._status = OpStatus.FAIL
            self.initialize_error = dict(
                type=e.__class__.__name__,
                message=str(e),
                trace=traceback.format_exc()
            )
            raise e from None
            
        return self._status
    
    @property
    def status(self) -> OpStatus:
        return self._status
    
    @OperatorUtils._catch_runtime_errors
    def run(self, data, load_operations={}):
        if self._status == OpStatus.INITIALIZED:
            response = self.loader.load(data, **load_operations)
        else:
            raise StatusError(
                f'Can not run while Loader is {self._status}')
            
        return response
    
    
class TaskOpsUtils:
    """
    A base class for managing the operations of a Task.
    :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
    :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
    :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
    :attribute:
    - handle_result: The result of the handle operation.
    - wrangle_result: The result of the wrangle operation.
    - load_result: The result of the load operation.
    - error: None if no error occurred during the operation, otherwise contains the error information.
    - operations: A dictionary that contains the status of each operation in the task.
    - data: A dictionary that contains the results of each operation in the task.
    :method:
    - get_response(operator): Return the response for the specified operation.
    - _run_operation(op, runner, passable, skip_status_update=False): Run an operation.
    - update_status(): Update the overall status of the task.
    """
    def __init__(self, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None):
        """
        Initialize the TaskOpsUtils class.
        :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
        :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
        :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
        """
        self.handle = handle
        self.wrangler = wrangler
        self.loader = loader

        self.handle_result = None
        self.wrangle_result = None
        self.load_result = None
        self.error = None
        
        self.operations = {'handle': TaskStatus.PENDING}
        if wrangler:
            self.operations.update({'wrangle': TaskStatus.PENDING})
        if loader:
            self.operations.update({'load': TaskStatus.PENDING})
    
    def get_response(self, operator):
        """
        Return the response for the specified operation.
        :param operator: The name of the operation.
        :return: The response of the operation.
        """
        return self.data[operator]
    
    def _run_operation(self, op, runner, passable, skip_status_update=False):
        """
        Run an operation.
        :param op: The name of the operation to run.
        :param runner: The callable for running the operation.
        :param passable: The argument to pass to the runner.
        :param skip_status_update: Skip updating the task's status.
        :return: The status of the operation.
        """
        # TODO: Clean this up, make it redundant or more intuitive to debug... its confusing.
        self.operations[op] = TaskStatus.INCOMPLETE

        response, self.error = runner.run(passable)
        status = TaskStatus.FAIL if self.error is not None else TaskStatus.COMPLETE

        self.operations[op] = status
        
        # TODO: Update this. Does there really need to be unique handling ber type in here...?
        # Should self.data be stored in the bottom derived classes?
        if self.__class__.__name__ == 'MultiRequestTask' and op == 'handle':
            self.data[op].append(response)
        else:
            self.data[op] = response
            

        if not skip_status_update:
            self.update_status()

        return status, response

    
class Task(TaskOpsUtils):
    """
    A base class for managing a task.
    :param name: The name of the task.
    :param req_dict: The request dictionary for the task.
    :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
    :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
    :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
    :param description: The description of the task.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    :attribute:
    - _status: The status of the task. Default is TaskStatus.PENDING.
    - name: The name of the task.
    - description: The description of the task.
    - data: The response data from task operators.
    - info: A mapping proxy type containing information about the task.
    :method:
    - run(): Run the task.
    - update_status(): Updates the status of the task.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, req_dict, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None, description=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the Task class.
        :param name: The name of the task.
        :param req_dict: The request dictionary for the task.
        :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
        :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
        :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
        :param description: The description of the task.
        :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
        """
        super().__init__(handle, wrangler, loader)

        self._status = TaskStatus.PENDING
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.data = dict(
            handle=None,
            wrangle=None,
            load=None
        )
        self.info = MappingProxyType({
            'name': name,
            'description': description,
            'type': self.__class__.__name__,
            'req': req_dict,
            'handle': handle,
            'wrangler': wrangler,
            'loader': loader,
            **kwargs
        })

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Task(name='{self.name}', status='{self.status}'),"

    @property
    def status(self) -> TaskStatus:
        return self._status.value
    
    def run(self):
        statuses = {}
        for op in self.operations:
            status = None
            if op == 'handle':
                status = self.run_request(skip_status_update=True)
            elif op == 'wrangle' and self.operations['handle'] == TaskStatus.COMPLETE:
                status = self.run_wrangle(skip_status_update=True)
            elif op == 'load' and self.operations['wrangle'] == TaskStatus.COMPLETE:
                status = self.run_load(skip_status_update=True)

            statuses[op] = status

        self.update_status()
        return statuses

    def update_status(self):
        if len(set(self.operations.values())) == 1:
            self._status = set(self.operations.values()).pop()
        else:
            self._status = TaskStatus.INCOMPLETE

class SingleRequestTask(Task):
    """
    A class for managing a single request task. Inherits from the base Task class.
    :param name: The name of the task.
    :param request: The request for the task.
    :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
    :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
    :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    :attribute:
    - request: The request for the task.
    
    :method:
    - run_request(): Runs the request for the task.
    - run_wrangle(): Runs the wrangler for the task.
    - run_load(): Runs the loader for the task.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, request, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, request, handle, wrangler, loader, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def run_request(self, skip_status_update=False):
        status, response = self._run_operation('handle', self.handle, self.request, skip_status_update)
        return status

    def run_wrangle(self, skip_status_update=False):
        status, response = self._run_operation('wrangle', self.wrangler, self, skip_status_update)
        return status

    def run_load(self, skip_status_update=False):
        status, response = self._run_operation('load', self.loader, self, skip_status_update)
        return status

    
class MultiRequestTask(Task):
    """
    A class for managing multiple requests. Inherits from the base Task class.
    :param name: The name of the task.
    :param request: The requests for the task.
    :param handle: A callable for handling the request.
    :param wrangler: A callable for wrangling the data from handle.
    :param loader: A callable for loading the data from wrangler.
    :param kwargs: Other keyword arguments.
    :attribute:
    - requests: The requests for the task.
    :method:
    - run_request(): Runs the requests for the task.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, requests, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None, **kwargs):      
        super().__init__(name, requests, handle, wrangler, loader, **kwargs)
        self.requests: dict = requests
        self.pattern = re.compile(r'<<(.*?)>>')
        self.cached_unique_values = {}
        self.data.update(handle=list())
        
    def run_request(self, skip_status_update=False):
        statuses = dict()
        pattern = self.pattern
        
        # Use the stored unique values if possible
        def hook(match, separator):
            in_string_var = match.group(1)
            if in_string_var in self.cached_unique_values:
                unique_values = self.cached_unique_values[in_string_var]
            else:
                unique_values = last_response[in_string_var].unique().tolist()
                self.cached_unique_values[in_string_var] = unique_values
            
            return separator.join(map(str, unique_values))
        
        last_response = None
        for _iter, request in self.requests.items():
            if last_response is not None:
                separator = request.get("%separator%", ", ")
                request = json.loads(pattern.sub(lambda x: hook(x, separator), json.dumps(request)))
            
            status, response = self._run_operation('handle', self.handle, request, skip_status_update)
            last_response = json_normalize(response)
            statuses.update({_iter:status})
                                  
            if status is not TaskStatus.COMPLETE:
                break
        
        return statuses
                                  
    def run_wrangle(self, skip_status_update=False):
        status, response = self._run_operation('wrangle', self.wrangler, self, skip_status_update)
        return status

    def run_load(self, skip_status_update=False):
        status, response = self._run_operation('load', self.loader, self, skip_status_update)
        return status
        
        
class TaskManagementUtils:
    """
    A class for managing multiple tasks and handling reading of tasks.
    
    :param tasks: A list of tasks as dictionaries, with task information.
    :attribute:
    - operator_statuses: A dictionary to store the statuses of the handle, wrangler and loader callables.
    - task_map: A dictionary mapping task names to task objects.
    :method:
    - dynamically_read(raw_tasks, task_kwargs=dict()): Dynamically reads the task information, replacing in-string {{variables}} with kwarg values.
    - read_tasks(tasks_file_path=None, task_kwargs=None, dynamic_reader=None): Reads task information from file or returns existing tasks.
    - task_obj_from_dict(task, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None): Creates a task object from a task dictionary.
    - add_task(self, task_name, task_obj=None, task_dict=None): Adds a task to the task_map.
    - get_task_status(self, task_name): Gets the status of a task.
    - get_task_statuses(self): Gets the statuses of all tasks.
    - get_task_status_counts(self): Gets the count of tasks in each status.
    - run_task(self, task_name): Runs a task by the given name, raises ValueError if task not found.
    - get_task_data(self, task_name, operator=None): Gets the data of a task by the given name, returns all data if operator is None.
    - get_all_tasks_data(self, operator=None): Gets the data of all tasks, returns all data for each task if operator is None.
    - get_task(self, task_name): Gets a task by the given name, raises ValueError if task not found.
    """
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        self.operator_statuses = dict(
            handle = None,
            wrangler = None,
            loader = None)
        task_objs = [
            self.task_obj_from_dict(
                task_data, self.handle, self.wrangler, self.loader
            ) for task_data in tasks]
        
        self.task_map = {task.name: task for task in task_objs}

    # Handles dynamic reading of in-string variables
    @staticmethod
    def dynamically_read(raw_tasks, task_kwargs=dict()):
        regex_pattern = re.compile(r'{{(.*?)}}')
        
        # Hook to replace in-string {{variables}} with kwarg values
        def regex_hook(match):            
            if not match.group(1) in task_kwargs:
                raise ValueError(
                    f'"{match.group(1)}" was dynamically entered '
                    f'but no value was specified for this key.')
            else:
                return task_kwargs[match.group(1)]
            
        # Hook to catch in-string {{variables}}
        def json_hook(_dict):
            for key, val in _dict.items():
                _dict[key] = json.loads(
                    regex_pattern.sub(regex_hook, json.dumps(val)))

            return _dict

        # Returns the filled tasks
        with raw_tasks:
            return json.loads(
                raw_tasks.read(),
                object_hook=json_hook
            )
        
    @staticmethod
    def read_tasks(tasks_file_path=None, task_kwargs=None, dynamic_reader=None):
        with open(tasks_file_path) as raw_tasks:
            if task_kwargs:
                tasks = dynamic_reader(raw_tasks, task_kwargs)
            else:
                tasks = json.load(raw_tasks)
        task_names = set(task['name'] for task in tasks)
        if len(task_names) != len(tasks):
            duplicates = task_names - set(task['name'] for task in tasks)
            raise ValueError(f"Duplicate tasks with names: {duplicates}")

        return tasks
    
    @staticmethod
    def task_obj_from_dict(task, handle, wrangler=None, loader=None):
        name = task.pop('name')
        if task.get('request'):
            request = task.pop('request')
            task_obj = SingleRequestTask(name, request, handle, wrangler, loader, **task)
        elif task.get('requests'):
            request = task.pop('requests')
            task_obj = MultiRequestTask(name, request, handle, wrangler, loader, **task)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Either 'request' or 'requests' must be supplied.")

        return task_obj

    def add_task(self, task_name, task_obj=None, task_dict=None):
        if task_dict:
            task_obj = task_obj_from_dict(task_dict, self.handle, self.wrangler, self.loader)
            
        self.task_map.update({task_name:task_obj})
            
    def get_task_status(self, task_name):
        task = self.tasks.get(task_name)
        if task is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Task {task_name} not found")
            
        return task.status
    
    def get_task_statuses(self):
        statuses = dict()
        for task_name, task in self.task_map.items():
            statuses.update({task_name:task.status})
            
        return statuses
    
    def get_task_status_counts(self):
        statuses = dict(
            pending = 0,
            incomplete = 0,
            complete = 0,
            failed = 0,
        )
        
        for task_name, task in self.task_map.items():
            statuses[task.status] += 1
            
        return statuses
        
    def run_task(self, task_name):
        task = self.task_map.get(task_name)
        if task is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Task {task_name} not found")
        
        status = task.run()
        return status
    
    def get_task_data(self, task_name, operator=None):
        task = self.task_map.get(task_name)
        if task is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Task {task_name} not found")
        
        if operator:
            data = task.data[operator]
        else:
            data = task.data
            
        return data

    def get_all_tasks_data(self, operator=None):
        data = dict()
        
        if operator:
            for task_name, task in self.task_map.items():
                data.update({task_name:task.data[operator]})
        else:
            for task_name, task in self.task_map.items():
                data.update({task_name:task.data})
            
        return data   
    
    def get_task(self, task_name):
        task = self.task_map.get(task_name)
        if task is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Task {task_name} not found")
            
        return task

    
class Pipe(TaskManagementUtils):
    """
    A class for managing the execution of tasks within a pipeline.
    :param handle: An object that represents the handle operation.
    :param tasks: A list of tasks as dictionaries, with task information.
    :param tasks_file_path: A file path to a file containing the tasks.
    :param tasks_kwargs: A dictionary of variables to be replaced within the tasks.
    :param wrangler: An object that represents the wrangler operation.
    :param loader: An object that represents the loader operation.
    :param credential_manager: An object that manages the credentials.
    :param secret_id: An id to access a secret.
    :param name: The name of the pipeline.
    :attribute:
    - _status: A pipe status indicating if the pipeline is IDLE, INCOMPLETE, COMPLETE, or FAIL.
    - name: The name of the pipeline.
    - secret_id: An id to access a secret.
    - handle: An object that represents the handle operation.
    - wrangler: An object that represents the wrangler operation.
    - loader: An object that represents the loader operation.
    :property:
    - status: Returns the current status of the pipeline.
    :method:
    - repr(): Returns a string representation of the pipeline.
    - update_status(): Updates the status of the pipeline.
    - initialize_handle(credentials_obj): Initializes the handle with a given credentials object.
    - initialize_wrangler(): Initializes the wrangler, if it exists.
    - initialize_loader(): Initializes the loader, if it exists.
    - initialize(credentials_obj): Initializes the pipeline, including the handle, wrangler, and loader.
    - run(): Runs every task in the pipe and then updates _status
    Inherits all methods from the parent class, TaskManagementUtils.
    """
    def __init__(self, handle, tasks=None, tasks_file_path=None, tasks_kwargs=None, 
                 wrangler=None, loader=None, secret_id=None, name=None):
        self._status: PipeStatus = PipeStatus.IDLE
        self.name = name
        self.secret_id = secret_id
        self.handle = Handle(handle)
        self.wrangler = Wrangler(wrangler) if wrangler else None
        self.loader = Loader(loader) if loader else None
        tasks = tasks if tasks is not None else self.read_tasks(
            tasks_file_path, tasks_kwargs, dynamic_reader=self.dynamically_read)
        super().__init__(tasks)
        
        self._pipe_failed = False  
        
    @property
    def status(self) -> PipeStatus:
        return self._status   

    def __repr__(self):
        task_strs = [task.__repr__() for task in self.task_map.values()]
        task_str = '\n'.join(task_strs)
        indented_task_str = textwrap.indent(task_str, '  ')
        return (
            f"Pipe(name='{self.name}', status='{self._status.value}',\n"
                    f"{indented_task_str}\n)")
    
    def update_status(self):
        status_counts = self.get_task_status_counts()
        
        if status_counts[TaskStatus.PENDING.value] == len(self.task_map):
            pass
        elif status_counts[TaskStatus.COMPLETE.value] == len(self.task_map):
            self._status = PipeStatus.COMPLETE
        else:
            self._status = PipeStatus.INCOMPLETE

        return self.status
    
    def initialize_handle(self, credentials_obj):
        status = self.handle.initialize(credentials_obj)
        self.operator_statuses.update(handle=status)
        if status == OpStatus.FAIL:
            self._status = PipeStatus.FAIL
            
        return status
    
    def initialize_wrangler(self):
        if self.wrangler:
            status = self.wrangler.initialize()
            self.operator_statuses.update(wrangler=status)

            return status
    
    def initialize_loader(self):
        if self.loader:
            status = self.loader.initialize()
            self.operator_statuses.update(wrangler=status)

            return status
        
    def initialize(self, credentials_obj):
        handle_status = self.initialize_handle(credentials_obj)
        self.initialize_wrangler()
        self.initialize_loader()
        if self._status == PipeStatus.IDLE and handle_status == OpStatus.INITIALIZED:
            self._status = PipeStatus.READY
        
        return self.operator_statuses
        
    def run(self):
        for task_name, task in self.task_map.items():
            new_status = task.run()
        
        pipe_status = self.update_status()
        return pipe_status
    
    
class Pipeline(Pipe):
    """
    A class for managing and executing pipelines made up of individual pipes.
    :param pipes: A list of dictionaries representing pipes in the pipeline.
    :param pipeline_id: (Optional) An identifier for the pipeline.
    :method:
    - `initialize_pipe(pipe_name)`: Initializes a single pipe in the pipeline.
    - `initialize_pipes(pipe_names)`: Initializes multiple pipes in the pipeline.
    - `initialize()`: Initializes all pipes in the pipeline.
    - `run_task(pipe_name, task_name)`: Executes a single task in a pipe.
    - `run_pipe(pipe_name)`: Executes all tasks in a single pipe.
    - `get_pipe(pipe_name)`: Returns a single pipe in the pipeline.
    - `get_pipe_data(pipe_name, operator=None)`: Returns data generated by a pipe.
    :attribute:
    - `id`: An identifier for the pipeline.
    - `credential_manager`: An object for managing credentials.
    - `pipes`: A dictionary mapping pipe names to pipes.
    """
    def __init__(self, pipeline_id: str, pipes: [dict,], credential_manager: 'func'):
        #self.loader = loader
        self.id = pipeline_id
        self.credential_manager = credential_manager
        self.pipes = MappingProxyType({pipe.name:pipe for pipe in pipes})
    
    def __repr__(self):
        pipe_strs = [pipe.__repr__() for pipe in self.pipes.values()]
        pipe_str = '\n'.join(pipe_strs)
        indented_pipe_str = textwrap.indent(pipe_str, '  ')
        return (
            f"Pipeline(id='{self.id}',\n"
                    f"{indented_pipe_str}\n)")
    
    @staticmethod
    def _check_pipe_not_failed(pipe):
        if pipe._pipe_failed:
            raise Exception("Pipeline failed earlier, cannot run further operations")
    
    def initialize_pipe(self, pipe_name):
        pipe = self.pipes[pipe_name]    
        credential_obj = self.credential_manager(pipe.secret_id)
        status = pipe.initialize(credential_obj)
            
        return status  
        
    def initialize_pipes(self, pipe_names):
        results = dict()
        for pipe_name in pipe_names:
            results.update({pipe_name:self.initialize_pipe(pipe_name)})
            
        return results
            
    def initialize(self):
        results = self.initialize_pipes(self.pipes.keys()) 
        return results
    
    def run_task(self, pipe_name, task_name):
        self._check_pipe_not_failed(pipe)
        self.pipes[pipe_name].run_task(task_name)     
        
    def run_pipe(self, pipe_name):
        pipe = self.pipes[pipe_name]
        self._check_pipe_not_failed(pipe)
        result = pipe.run()
        
        return result
    
    def run(self):
        results = dict()
        for pipe_name, pipe in self.pipes.items():
            self._check_pipe_not_failed(pipe)
            result = pipe.run()
            results.update({pipe_name:result})
        
        return results
    
    def get_pipe(self, pipe_name):
        return self.pipes[pipe_name]
    
    def get_pipe_data(self, pipe_name, operator=None):
        pipe = self.pipes[pipe_name]
        data = pipe.get_all_tasks_data(operator=operator)
        
        return data
```

Example init:

```
Pipeline(pipeline_id='Example',
    credential_manager=credential_manager,
    pipes = [
        Pipe(
            name='gads_pipe',
            secret_id='Ads',
            tasks_file_path=r'pipeline\tasks\g_ads_tasks.json',
            tasks_kwargs=dict(start_date=start, end_date=end),
            handle=Google_Ads,
            wrangler=G_Ads_Wrangler,
            #loader= No Loader Functionality Yet :(
        ),
        Pipe(
            name='ga4_pipe',
            secret_id='GA4',
            tasks_file_path=r'pipeline\tasks\ga4_tasks.json',
            tasks_kwargs=dict(start_date=start, end_date=end),
            handle=Google_Analytics4,
            wrangler=GA4_Wrangler,
            #loader= No Loader Functionality Yet :(
        )
    ]
)

>>>
Pipeline(id='Example',
  Pipe(name='gads_pipe', status='idle',
    Task(name='all_campaign_metrics', status='pending'),
  )
  Pipe(name='ga4_pipe', status='idle',
    Task(name='lp_visits', status='pending'),
    Task(name='desktop_downloads', status='pending'),
    Task(name='lp_cta_clicks', status='pending'),
    Task(name='organic_search_metrics', status='pending'),
    Task(name='signup_pages_visits', status='pending'),
    Task(name='signups_web_tracking', status='pending'),
  )
)
```